# Why does print error in the console without adding System.err.println to the code?

Tags: java

The error print in the console if an error found while compiling the code.
How does it work without adding System.err.println

Comment: Please share the relevant part of your code (even better, a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), the exact error you're getting and what you expected to happen instead. More generally, it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Actually I am asking how does it work for any code either it is compiled successfully or not. TY

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't confuse errors you get when *compiling* your code with errors that occur when *running* it.

Compile-time errors are printed by the compiler, not your code. Whether your code uses `System.err` or not isn't relevant. The compiler has `System.err.println`—or something equivalent—somewhere in its own source code.

Let's say I tried to compile this program:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        Hello world!
    }
}
```

Does the compiler need me to use `System.err` in order to tell me that `Hello world!` is wrong? Certainly not, right? A syntax error is a syntax error.

Comment: JRE also has something like System. err to print errors?

Comment: Not the JRE. The compiler is part of the JDK. The compiler is itself a program with its own code, probably hundreds of thousands of lines of code. That code has error printouts, yes.

Answer (score 0):

JVM catches uncought exception and uses standard error output stream to print the details of that error.